# Dropbox Sync API cancel upload

Tags: ios7, dropbox-api

Is there any way to cancel the file upload of Dropbox Sync API? 
I want to cancel upload of the files that hasn't been uploaded but left the uploaded files on the Dropbox.
Is it possible with Sync API?

Comment: See also https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=118291 on the Dropbox API forum.

Comment: Funny, it's my own question :)

Comment: Yes, of course... it's identical. I linked the two so people don't duplicate effort in answering the question in both places.

Comment: Was any answer given on the dropbox forum? The link is dead now :(

Comment: Nope, nobody replied. I gave up the looking for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Dropbox support:

> Depending on your use case though, you may want to just delete the
>   file. (I.e., if the user wants to cancel the upload because they don't
>   actually want to sync the file, just delete the file from the
>   DBFilesystem.)

This worked well for me.

Comment: Sounds pretty easy :D Thanks